# Using read.arff() function in R and importing .arff files

Tags: r

I am trying to import this dataset of .arff type

```
file_location <- file.path("/Users","supreet","Downloads","Chronic_Kidney_Disease1/")
Chronic_Kidney_Disease <- read.arff(paste(file_location,"chronic_kidney_disease.arff",sep=""))
```

But it is throwing the following error

> Error in file(arff_file, "rb") : cannot open the connection In
>   addition: Warning message: In file(arff_file, "rb") :   cannot open
>   file
>   '/Users/supreet/Downloads/Chronic_Kidney_Disease1/chronic_kidney_disease.arff.arff':
>   No such file or directory

Also, if remove .arff extension as it is already appended :

```
file_location <- file.path("/Users","supreet","Downloads","Chronic_Kidney_Disease1/")
Chronic_Kidney_Disease <- read.arff(paste(file_location,"chronic_kidney_disease",sep=""))
```

I get this error:

> Error: XML content does not seem to be XML:
>   '/Users/supreet/Downloads/Chronic_Kidney_Disease1/chronic_kidney_disease.xml'
>   In addition: Warning message: In matrix(unlist(strsplit(arff_data,
>   ",", fixed = T)), ncol = num_attrs,  :   data length [10001] is not a
>   sub-multiple or multiple of the number of rows [401]
>   >

Comment: When I run `paste(file_location,"chronic_kidney_disease.arff",sep="")` I get `"/Users/supreet/Downloads/Chronic_Kidney_Disease1chronic_kidney_disease.arff"`  Notice the missing slash /

Comment: This is because i have appended it in the file location path
file_location <- file.path("/Users","supreet","Downloads","Chronic_Kidney_Disease1/"

Comment: Yes, but it is a mistake. You need the slash to have a legitimate path. No wonder that R cannot find the file.